# Interaction in the selection of row

Tags: usability, interaction-design, data-tables

[image: **enter image description here**]

Scenario: 
After the search, the name list gets populated on the popup window.
User needs to select any one of the rows and continue and it which will get added into the next table.

In option 1, the user will select any one of the radio buttons, then press the DONE button to insert the data into the next table.

Option 2: User will click on the row and row will get highlighted & selected with color and then press the done button to insert the data into the next table

Which interaction is more user-friendly or stands in the usability principles

Answer (score 2):

You could consider combining the two options. The radio button provides a nice signifier to the user that they can select, but it's a little odd for it to be outside of the row it would be selecting.

In addition you should consider how hover states might help communicate selection possibilities (assuming this design is for a desktop environment).

Comment: Thanks Will, This design is only for the desktop environment user. The radio button is only inside the table, I missed creating space inside the table column.

Answer (score 1):

It's need to inform user about possibility to click this item (np hover effect)

**What is the main objective of selecting one item?**

I think based on this information a design should be created

---

Look how google solve this problem in gmail (It's combination of both options)

- If you need to select one item, you just see it - interaction to details of item (hover effect used)(3 on photo)
- If you need select multiple items and make operation with them - it's
  possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Classic Radio buttons next to table rows doesnt ring a bell for me. 
 
I suggest use option 2, **on hover** on the row; 
 
- make decent background colour interaction, 
 
- show cursor pointer for clicking, 
 
- and on the very left show appropriate icon. 
 
 
Once pressed you can leave icon there. If only one selection should be available icon can be just circle, or anything other that fits into context or that informs your user what awaits him next.

Comment: Thanks for the reply xul

Answer (score 0):

Good question,

Using architecture information I think the radio buttons should be inside the table, maybe in their own column. Also, I didn't see clearly that I could press on the row just with the overlight.

I bet you could reinforce the two ideas mixing them and adding some text instructions.

"Choose any of the rows" and mix the radio button with the highlighted area.

Comment: Thanks, The radio button is only inside the table, I missed creating space inside the table column.